Protect fusermount -u from unmount FS when not allowed
I am developing FS to do some nasty tasks. It would restrict file access. It will asks user about he/she allows file open/create/move/removal/etc.
I create executable with set group id. Because user must mount FS, I mount as user and next change group id to access protected directory.
Problem is I cannot protect from unmount operation. Some bad guy could unmount FS and perform normal file operations, so if user mount some protected directory to ~/bin (for example), someone could unmount from ~/bin and write custom executable to ~/bin. The same about config files.
What I trying to do is to remove this piece of code:
    if (fuse_set_signal_handlers(session) != 0) {
      goto end1;
    }

And write something like this:
    do {
      (void) fuse_session_loop_mt(session, &config);
    } while (!grant_access(OP_UNMOUNT, NULL, NULL));
    fuse_session_unmount(session);
    fuse_session_destroy(session);

But this do not work. I use libfuse in version 3 and low-level libfuse API.
EDIT 1:
I try to use:
setcap cap_dac_override=ep /usr/bin/securehome-daemon
setcap cap_setuid=^C /usr/bin/securehome-daemon

Program does change UID firstly, but libfuse3 complain I do not have right to mount filesystem, but I set cap_dac_override.
EDIT 2:
I correct setcap invocation:
>setcap 'cap_setuid=ep cap_dac_override=ep' /usr/bin/securehome-daemon 
>getcap /usr/bin/securehome-daemon
/usr/bin/securehome-daemon cap_dac_override,cap_setuid=ep

But libfuse still complain.
Edit 3:
I now have code looking like this:
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int config_dir;
    int ret = 1;
    struct fuse_loop_config config;
    struct fuse_session *session;
    struct fuse_cmdline_opts opts;
    char *mountpoint;
    struct passwd *user_cred = getpwnam("sechome");

    switch_user("sechome");
    setenv("USER", "sechome", 1);

    mount_point = argv[1];

    if (NULL == user_cred) {
      perror("[Critical] Unable to get user data - maybe system is not configured properly");
      exit(1);
    }
    printf("UID %d GID %d MOUT_POINT \"%s\"\n", user_cred->pw_uid, user_cred->pw_gid, mount_point);
    if (-1 == chown(mount_point, user_cred->pw_uid, user_cred->pw_gid)) {
      perror("[Critical] Unable to protect directory");
      exit(1);
    }

    if (-1 == chmod(mount_point,S_IRWXO|S_IRWXG|S_IRWXG)) {
      perror("[Critical] Unable to share directory");
      exit(1);
    }

    if (false == init(&argc, argv, get_real_inode(FUSE_ROOT_ID),&config_dir)) {
      goto end1;
    }


    main_dir_helper = config_dir;


    if (2 > argc) {
      puts("[Core] Bad number of parameters");
      print_usage(argv[0]);
      fuse_cmdline_help();
      fuse_lowlevel_help();
      goto end1;
    }

    struct fuse_args args = FUSE_ARGS_INIT(argc, argv);

    if (fuse_parse_cmdline(&args, &opts) != 0) {
        goto end1;
    }

    session = fuse_session_new(&args,FS_obtain_operations(),sizeof(struct fuse_lowlevel_ops ),NULL );
    if (session == NULL) {
      goto end1;
    }

#if 0
    if (fuse_set_signal_handlers(session) != 0) {
      goto end1;
    }
#endif

    switch_user("sechome");

    if (fuse_session_mount(session, argv[1]) != 0) {
      goto end1;
    }
....
}

FS was properly mounted, but my user do not have access. How to pass allow others from C code to libfuse3? Have I do change my OS config (I prefer to do not do this).

It now works. I set cap_chown,cap_setuid uid=root, gid=root , chmod u+s. I will shown C code tomorrow. If you wish, you could search for securehome code. I must add code to check directory ownership, code to allow of unmount, etc., but unmounting protection is almost done.
